# ajax.actionlink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can i accomodate  Html.RouteLink in( ajax.actionlink with updatetargetid="divid")in

> 

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are looking to do?

Comment: i have already implemented paging with html.routelink. the page is refreshing which i  don't want to do. so i am going for ajax.actionlink instead of html.routelink . if there is a way i can accomodate my html.routelink in ajax.actionlink it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Ajax.RouteLink?

```
<% AjaxOptions ajaxopts = new AjaxOptions(){HttpMethod="Get",
InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId="divid"}; %>

<%=Ajax.RouteLink("First","Pager",ajaxopts, new {page=1})%>
```

Just make sure that your Route returns a partial view for the pager, not the whole view. Either via a separate action or through a bool in the route to return either View or Partial.